# HTML: How do I change table content using document.getElementByID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to being a Webmaster and I was wondering if it was possible to dynamically change an img src by clicking a button in html.

Theoretical Goal:
There are 4 buttons on my web page, each button changes content on the page using three functions:

1. Designated to change the header
2. Designated to change paragraphs
3. Designated to change a table

I'm embedding the code into a Weebly site, since that is the Web Hosting our previous webmaster chose. So this may not even be possible considering how limited Weebly is.

You can see my current and full version of the code: [HERE](http://pastebin.com/s7QJfkA8).

The shortened version can be located: [HERE](http://pastebin.com/3k9FmAF8).

I read around that I should use `document.getElementById("").src` for images, but I haven't had any luck. I have been able to update the Headers and Paragraphs, so that isn't too bad. I just can't update anything in my table. Anything outside of the table can be updated.

I also tried moving the `ID: "R1C1"` into all of the child and parent tags separately, until I got to the root tag.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using Weebly can be a bit challenging, because any custom code that you lay in, might be overwritten the next time you do a publish.  When you have a solution that works, it should reside in an external javascript file, and in the header, reference/include that javascript file.

Comment: I'd also recommend using jquery for this as opposed to document.getElementById()

Comment: `document.getElementById("R1C1")` will get you the `td` and not the `image`

Comment: jQuery is absolutely overkill for something this simple.

Comment: I recommend you that before use jQuery, learn and understand as much as possible native javascript 

Comment: @LShetty, I understand that is where it is placed currently, though I did place it in the image tag (Please see my line about placing it in all child and parent tags) and I still didn't see results. :/

Comment: @Adam T, It can be a hassle, which is why I'm only running a test page until I'm ready for a full publish. I strongly dislike Weebly but I don't have much of a choice, so I'm trying to work with what I have.

Comment: @WebApprentice yes, I completely understand. One of my last jobs had that kind of situation as well.  Keeping any functionality in an external file should definitely save you the headache of losing the code in the event that a publish wipes it out.

Comment: @Adam T, thank you for the heads up. I'm currently running a test from the page itself but when it's all finished and ready to be uploaded I will call to it as an external file.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with Weebly, so this may not apply.

The image tag that you want to change has to have the id attribute on it. Then use document.getElementById to select that image tag, and change the src after that.

```js
document.getElementById('btnChangeImage').addEventListener('click', changeImage);

function changeImage(){
  var img = document.getElementById('imgChangeMe');
  img.src = 'http://placehold.it/200x50';
}
```

```html
<button id="btnChangeImage">Change Image</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Doesn't matter where this image is, you can select it by the ID</td>
    <td><img id="imgChangeMe" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have placed it in the image tag and the action still didn't work. (Please see my mention of placing the ID in all child and parent tags separately). When I tried placing it in the image tag, I was seeing the same results, even after publishing.

Comment: @Jon Hargett - nice code. WebApprentice, it worked for me (are you getting any errors?). You may want to do a view source as the older/previous code may have been cached in your browser.

Comment: @Adam T, I wasn't getting any errors which I'm okay with. Turns out, Weebly's editor has trouble interpreting code. I reuploaded the code from a better connection and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I was able to fix the problem. It wasn't an issue with the code, it was an issue with Weebly trying to process the code. As many of you mentioned, placing the ID in the image tag is a must, as I hoped and tried before. So it would look like this

```
<img id="R1C1" src="http://www.convertingsystems.com/uploads/2/6/8/5/26859557/6414565.jpg?222" alt="3001 Dual Turret Blown Film Winder" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%"/>
```

I can paste the code 5 times into the Weebly editor and get 5 different results. I went home where I have a much faster and more reliable connection, repasted my code, and it worked. Thanks for all of the replies though.